# how to improve responsive table view on mobile?

Tags: css, html-table, bootstrap-4, materialize

I using https://materializecss.com/table.html to make table

My html code like this :

```
<table class="responsive-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thr</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
        <th>Sun</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>09:00-13:00</li>
              <li>10:00-14:30</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>10:00-14:30</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>09:00-13:00</li>
              <li>10:00-14:30</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>09:00-13:00</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>09:00-13:00</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>09:00-13:00</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
          <ul>
              <li>-</li>
          </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The view of dekstop is neat. It like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YLea.png)

But the view of mobile is not nead. It like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2xds.png)

How do I tidy up the display on mobile? I need to use the ul tag inside the td tag

Update :

This is my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/oh94xncb/. It is still does not work

Comment: Can you post your CSS? We can't replicate the issue to debug without all of your code.

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein I use materialize.css. Look at this : https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.css

Answer (score 0):

With CSS flex display,

```
.responsive-table tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
```

how abaout this ?

Comment: Whats wrong ? Table width value is so high and it will flow to bottom.

Comment: can you show it using jsfiddle or codepan? I tried it, but it didn't work

Comment: Look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/oh94xncb/ . It does not work